# Why can't I serve static files with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having an issue where whenever I try to link my Express app's static files to change it's frontend, it isn't responding. This is my file format.

```
- app
-- api
--- routes.js
-- node_modules
-- public
--- img
--- css
---- styles.css
--- index.html
-- app.js
-- package-lock.json
-- package.json
```

As you can see, all the files are nested within the same folder. Routes.js file has just the routes, right now it has code to say "Hello World!" by using res.send. App.js is our main file. Inside it has,

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

require("./api/routes.js")(app);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This is the index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried so many ways to serve the static files, none worked. In my html I have a simple "Hello World2" script but it never goes through. Can anyone help me why this isn't working? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post also the index.html file ? maybe it's a problem on the script src path

And do you have any errors on console ?

Comment: I just added the edit. There are no errors on console, no.

Comment: Actually, I just fixed it. I think the code in routes.js was overriding the static files, so html was not showing up.

Comment: I think you got it, but move your `express.static(...)` code before you start adding other routes.

Comment: Move it? Where should I move it to? To routes.js? Because in that file is simply a module.exports = function(app) {} with space for future routes.

Comment: No, I mean move `app.use(express.static(...))` up, before you do `require("./api/routes.js")(app)`.

Answer (score -1):

Here what would I do is to use `res.render()` insted of `res.send()` (it would help you have cleaner folder structure too). In your `app.js` add this lines after creating `app` instance:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', 'views')
```

Add the first line if you are using a view engine( if you want dynamic pages and you don't want to create another server for the front-end, `ejs` is the easiest option). and the second line says to the app that if you reached `res.render('index')` render the `index.html` file or with the proper suffix of the view engine in the `views` folder.

If this didn't work out the problem would be from your routes.js. Add a comment and I will help you out.

Comment: sorry, this does not attempt to answer the question

Comment: why is that? I am using this way for months now and I got no problem with it, based on the question it would fix if the router is ok, if it is not the problem would be from the router. and could please say a solution if you think it is not the answer? @srknzl

Comment: serving a directory statically has nothing to do with template engines

Comment: I am not saying template engine would fix it or anything to do I just mentioned it

Comment: Just mentioning is ok in a comment not in an answer. answers supposed to "answer". really this is a stackoverflow rule